# Apache works on http and https, SVN only on http

Tags: svn

I asked a question about this before, and got most of it fixed.    If I switch off https redirect and go to http://mydomain.com/svn/test0, I get the authentication window popping up, and I can enter my AD credentials, and bingo.   Switching https redirect back on, if I go to http://mydomain.com I am automatically redirected to https, which is what I want, and the 'CerntOS test page' pops up.  Perfect.

The problem occurs when I want to go to one of my test repos via https.  Here is my httpd.conf file, with confidential information suitably hosed...

===

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin my.name@mycompany.com
        ServerName svn.mycompany.com
        ErrorLog logs/subversion-error_log
        CustomLog logs/subversion-access_log common
        Redirect permanent / https://svn.mycompany.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost svn.mycompany.com:443>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/wildcard.mycompany.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/wildcard.mycompany.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/intermediate.crt
        ServerName svn.mycompany.com
        ServerAdmin my.name@mycompany.com
        ErrorLog logs/subversion-error_log
        CustomLog logs/subversion-access_log common

<Location /svn>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /usr/local/subversion
        SVNListParentPath off
        AuthName "Subversion Repositories"

# NT Logon Details
        Require valid-user
        AuthBasicProvider file ldap
        AuthType Basic
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/svnpasswd
        AuthName "Subversion Server II"
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://our-pdc:389/OU=Company Name,DC=com,DC=co,DC=uk?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
        AuthLDAPBindDN "DOMAIN\subversion"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword XXXXXXX
        AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/httpd/conf/svnaccessfile

</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

===

Now, in ssl_error_log, I get

===

```
==> /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error_log <==
[Fri Nov 01 16:07:55 2013] [error] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] File does not exist: /var/www/html/svn
```

===

This comes from the DocumentRoot directive further up the httpd.conf file, which of course points to /var/www/html.  I know that this location is wrong, but how can I get SVN to serve the repo?

I tried an Alias directive as so ..

```
Alias /svn /usr/local/subversion
```

.. but this didn't work.  I tried to alter the Location directive. That didn't work either.

Can someone help?  I sense that this is so close to being solved ...

Thanks.

**Edit:** `apachectl -S` output:

```
[root@svn conf]# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
127.0.0.1:443 svn.mycompany.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1020) 
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and default servers:
default:443 svn.mycompany.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
*:80 is a NameVirtualHost
default server svn.mycompany.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1012)
port 80 namevhost svn.mycompany.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1012)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Looks like you've got a different SSL vhost that's getting the requests.  Provide the output from `apachectl -S`?

Comment: [root@svn conf]# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
127.0.0.1:443          svn.mycompany.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1020)
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443          svn.mycompany.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server svn.mycompany.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1012)
         port 80 namevhost svn.mycompany.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1012)
Syntax OK

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `Alias` should work, but you also have to setup `<Directory "/usr/local/subversion">` properly.

Comment: Thanks .. where do I put the Directory?  I've tried it inside the SSL VirtualHost, inside Location ... no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<VirtualHost svn.mycompany.com:443>` to `<VirtualHost *:443>`.

You have `svn.mycompany.com` resolving to `127.0.0.1` which is causing that bind to do nothing, and causing the `_default_:443` bind in `ssl.conf` to get the requests (service up the default test page).